# Replacing head section in a html response in httpd using mod_substitute

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I would like to replace <head> in the html response using mod_substitute. I am using httpd 2.2 to reverse proxy requests, down to the application server (weblogic).

Proxy defintions / mapping in httpd.conf are as below.
I am loading mod_substitute.so, mod_filter.so and mod_wl_22.so.

```
<Location /test>
    SetHandler weblogic-handler
    WebLogicCluster a.b.c.d:8080
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>

<Location "/">
    SetOutputFilter INFLATE;SUBSTITUTE;DEFLATE
    AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/xml
    Substitute "s#<head>#<!-- This is a comment --><head>#inq"
</Location>
```

I need the <head> in the html response substituted with <!-- This is a comment --><head> after I access the app, something similar to below.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><!-- This is a comment --><!-- This is a comment --><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /
on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

You can view the html response by "right clicking on the web page --> View page feature" from your web browser. I am using google chrome.

I get to see the substitution work only work when I access root URL (http://www.example.net/), but it does not work when I call a resource through the URL (http://www.example.net/test).

Is there a way to make the substitution work when URL is accessed with a resource.

Comment: Your substitution is defined under Location `/`.  So if you ask for `/test`, it will not apply.  Just move your substitution directives outside the Location, it should apply to all.